# Laravel 8 Invalid Date time while seeding

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I am new to laravel , I receive error while trying to seed data, I have done it successfully in two different tables but I am stuck at this one :
**Model**

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Project extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    public $timestamps = false;

    protected $fillable = [
        'Pmid',
        'Ministry',
        'P_name',
        'Budget',
    ];

    protected $casts = [
        'Registered_at' => 'datetime',
    ];
}
```

**Factory**

```
<?php

namespace Database\Factories;

use App\Models\Project;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\Factory;

class ProjectFactory extends Factory
{
    protected $model = Project::class;

    /**
     * Define the model's default state.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function definition()
    {
        return [
            'Pmid'          => $this->faker->unique()->name(),
            'Ministry'      => $this->faker->name(),
            'P_name'        => $this->faker->name(),
            'Budget'        => $this->faker->name(),
            'Registered_at' => now(),
        ];
    }
}
```

**Seeder**

```
<?php

namespace Database\Seeders;

use App\Models\Project;
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class ProjectTableSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        Project::factory()->count(20)->create();
    }
}
```

**Migration**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateProjectsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('projects', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('Pmid')->unique();
            $table->string('Ministry');
            $table->string('P_name');
            $table->integer('Budget');
            $table->timestamp('Registered_at');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('projects');
    }
}
```

**error**

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException
> SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1366 Incorrect integer value: 'Mathias Kuhlman' for column `laravel`.`projects`.`Budget` at row 1 (SQL: insert into `projects` (`Pmid`, `Ministry`, `P_name`, `Budget`, `Registered_at`) values (Nicholas Mayer, Ms. Donna Strosin, Hermann Bins, Mathias Kuhlman, 2021-12-05 08:36:39))

Comment: I'm not sure why you're getting *that* error for the `Budget` column. Have you manually updated your database table after migrating it? You have defined your `Budget` column as an `integer` though so it doesn't make sense to use `$this->faker->name()` for it's value as this will give you a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using

```
'Budget'        => $this->faker->name(),
```

to create the data, but your migration shows that that column should be an integer :

```
$table->integer('Budget');
```

I suspect you've just copied and pasted the faker rows without changing the type of value being faked.

Comment: Ohh you are right, thanks. Its a while I am stuck at this and I tried with different tables and datatypes to find out where the problem stands, I have wrote them down this time without noticing Budget datatype, I corrected it , but still have problem with date format.

Comment: No problem. Incidentally, generally best to use lowercase names for columns within MySQL. There's no technical issue, but if you always do that there's never any likelihood that your code will get thrown by you writing the uppercase version (Id) when it's lowercase name, or vice versa.

Comment: Alright, next time  I will consider it, but this version of Laravel deal with timestamp datatype differently, I tried as the same as the User defualt model for it but still giving me error!